# Changing terminal emulator from gnome-terminal to kitty breaks some functionality

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, update-alternatives

I've switched from gnome terminal to kitty. I ran

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and selected my terminal.

However, some actions still ran using the default gnome terminal.

I tried uninstalling gnome-terminal, but that didn't change anything.

The problems I have are that

- attempting to launch terminal with ulancher apps doesn't work
- 'open in terminal' with nautilus has disappeared

these are things that usually open with gnome terminal, but I want them to open with kitty.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details (ie. what software stack are you using; allowing details of the *dependency* requirements etc to be looked up)

Comment: cHECK THE VALUE OF $SHELL

Comment: What do you mean by "launching terminal aps"? That usually happens from the command line. "Open with terminal" in nautilus unfortunately is tied to Gnome-terminal indeed. There is a nautilus python extension that allows to implement that right click option for other terminals, or you could create a nautilus script.

Comment: @user1164434 Why would the value of `SHELL` be relevant here?

Answer (score -1):

You need to reinstall gnome-terminal. To do so, restart the system. At grub, pres `e` to enter grub config and at the end of line which starts with `“linux /boot/vmlinuz-...` add `init=/bin/bash`.
`Ctrl+x` to save boot
Then at the terminal that you get try to `apt install gnome-shell`. Hopefully this should solve the problem.

Comment: i still have a terminal, its just not fully functional.

Comment: @makerio OK, but you mention that you tried to uninstall gnome-terminal, and then you listed some problems that sound related to that. Can you please edit your question to clarify "that did not work" with regard to uninstalling gnome-terminal. Did you not uninstall it? Did you reinstall it? Did you have the problem that *open in terminal* disappeared before you uninstalled gnome-terminal, or did it just run gnome-terminal instead of your preferred emulator? Can you also state your goal? This answer tries to fix your loss of function issues, but maybe your goal is to have kitty perform them?

Comment: i edited it, douse this make it more clear? i have fixed the first issue, but nautulas still hasten't gave me the "open in terminal" option.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make a symlink.

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/kitty /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

any attempt to open gnome terminal will just open kitty

Comment: If `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` still exists, you have to (re-)move it first, else creating the symlink will fail due to existing target.